# How can I write a cursor in postgresql with update statement and using db link

Tags: postgresql

I am going to update the table of huge record from one DB to another DB.

Here I'm using a cursor function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Drug("Drug" text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   curs refcursor;
   rec record;
BEGIN

OPEN curs FOR EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || quote_ident("Drug") FOR UPDATE;

LOOP
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO rec;
    EXIT WHEN rec IS NULL;

    RAISE NOTICE '%', rec."Id";

    EXECUTE format('update statement with dblink', tbl)
    USING rec.ctid;
END LOOP;

END
$BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Is this correct?... or any other...

Please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

What I know dblink doesn't support cursors - cursors cannot be parameter of query (cursors in PostgreSQL are very careful, usually limited to transaction). So this idea is wrong. You can generate row updates - but it will be slow.

What you can do. You can use [FDW API](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/postgres-fdw.html) (foreign data wrappers API) and create permanent link (foreign table to second database). Then you can send a usual `UPDATE` statement to second database.

I have two databases `db1` and `db2`. `db1` is source database, `db2` is target database:

```
-- all is executed on db2
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
CREATE SERVER db1 FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (dbname 'db1');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR pavel
   SERVER db1 OPTIONS (user 'pavel');
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE db1_source(a int, b int)
   SERVER db1 OPTIONS (table_name 'source');
```

Now I have a FDW table db1_source and I can do UPDATE:

```
db2=# UPDATE target SET b = db1_source.b 
         FROM db1_source WHERE target.a =  db1_source.a;
```

This is most effective way how to do UPDATE based on data in other database